# Htmlunit in Webservice

Tags: java, web-services, web-scraping, jax-ws, htmlunit

I am trying to create a web service that scrap data from JustDial. I am able to run the code when using a simple java application rather than Dynamic Web Project in the form of web service.

```
WebClient client = new WebClient();
```

This is the line where the code stops. Next line is not executed and there is no exception.
All the libraries have been imported.

Comment: Did you try to add a browser version like `WebClient webClient = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.FIREFOX_38);` ?

Comment: Yes. I have tried CHROME and FIREFOX_38